# Source map support for Safari on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, mobile-safari, source-maps, safari-web-inspector

Safari 7.0.2 for Mac supports source maps, but when using it to remote debug a webapp on iOS 7.1 it doesn't show my non-minified JS sources. Same for SCSS sources.

I thought source map were supported by the developer tools (Safari for Mac in this case), not the browser it self.

Is there a way to make it work ?